# No signature of method: build_1fqop3ps6hvqzh1lfs04fdnyr.android() is applicable for argument types

Tags: android, react-native

When I run my react-native project, it keeps showing the following error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_1fqop3ps6hvqzh1lfs04fdnyr.android() is applicable for argument types: 
(build_1fqop3ps6hvqzh1lfs04fdnyr$_run_closure1) values: 
[build_1fqop3ps6hvqzh1lfs04fdnyr$_run_closure1@48507c2]
```

Here is my app/build.gradle:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s572/sh/414a3bb3-ceb4-6804-7caf-8ad7efc4e324/0f60556d96e5035b20699ec8aa303c44

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem and i resolve it by rewriting the gradle code.

```
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
    }

}
```

if you make sure your gradle structure is same as mine, ctrl c my code and replace yours may helpful. i just do it to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A typo caused the issue for me. I wrote `versxionCode 43` instead of `versionCode 43`.

Comment: Are you sure that you provide a solution to the problem as described at the top of this page? According to [answer]? If not please delete your post. For that, as an unregistered user you need to first register for that - or flag your own post for a moderator to do the deleting for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).